# How can I make my model translator usage more concise?

Tags: c#

##### The Problem

I'm updating a system to use OOP where a *major* process of the system is to translate data between many providers. The translations happen in a many to many fashion. So provider A, B and C all have their own definitions of what a `Corgi` object is. For example;

```
public struct CorgiA { public int FluffLevel { get; set; } }
public struct CorgiB { public short MuchFluff { get; set; } }
public struct CorgiC { public int Fluff { get; set; } }
```

The business requirement are:

- Use concrete types.
- Ensure data models for a given provider, *match* their respective documentation.

  - This includes naming and type specification.

As a result, typical interfaces won't work due to naming and type mismatch possibilities. I recently asked this question on Software Engineering to get some alternatives and the answer I accepted is what I've decided to proceed with, at least for now, as a solution.

##### The Current Solution

I have a simple translation setup that involves an interface that takes two type arguments:

```
public interface ITranslatable<T1, T2> {
    T2 Translate();
    T1 Translate(T2 input);
}
```

This is implemented on models that I want to translate, for example:

```
public struct Corgi {
    public int FluffLevel { get; set; }
    public Corgi(int fluffLevel) => FluffLevel = fluffLevel;
}
public sealed class MyCorgi : ITranslatable<MyCorgi, Corgi> {
    public int FluffLevel { get; set; }
    public MyCorgi(int fluffLevel) => FluffLevel = fluffLevel;
    public Corgi Translate() => new(FluffLevel);
    public MyCorgi Translate(Corgi input) => new(input.FluffLevel);
}
public sealed class YourCorgi : ITranslatable<YourCorgi, Corgi> {
    public int MuchFluff { get; set; }
    public YourCorgi(int muchFluff) => MuchFluff = muchFluff;
    public Corgi Translate() => new(MuchFluff);
    public YourCorgi Translate(Corgi input) => new(input.FluffLevel);
}
```

The usage is rather straightforward (executed in the main of a console application):

```
var myCorgi = new MyCorgi(100);
var yourCorgi = new YourCorgi(-1);
yourCorgi = yourCorgi.Translate(myCorgi.Translate());
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourCorgi));
```

##### An Example Implementation

I've created the following example implementation to demonstrate a use case. Keep in mind however, since this has no implementation currently, I've used the corgi models from above. This example has a "registration service" that fetches corgi data from one provider, and registers it with another.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#region Framework Assembly

public interface ITranslatable<T1, T2> {
    T2 Translate();
    T1 Translate(T2 input);
}
public struct Corgi {
    public int FluffLevel { get; set; }
    public Corgi(int fluffLevel) => FluffLevel = fluffLevel;
}
public interface ICorgiRegistrationServiceHandler {
    bool TryFetchCorgis(out IEnumerable<Corgi> corgis);
    void ProcessCorgi(Corgi corgi);
}

#endregion

#region My Corgi Provider Assembly

public sealed class MyCorgi : ITranslatable<MyCorgi, Corgi> {
    public int FluffLevel { get; set; }
    public MyCorgi(int fluffLevel) => FluffLevel = fluffLevel;
    public Corgi Translate() => new(FluffLevel);
    public MyCorgi Translate(Corgi input) => new(input.FluffLevel);
}

// The fact that this is static is part of another task. Ignore that fact for the purposes of this review.
public static class MyCorgiService {
    private static Random _random = new Random();
    public static IEnumerable<MyCorgi> FetchCorgis(int numberOfCorgis) {
        var result = new List<MyCorgi>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCorgis; i++)
            result.Add(new MyCorgi(_random.Next(30, 100)));

        return result;
    }
}

#endregion

#region Your Corgi Provider Assembly

public sealed class YourCorgi : ITranslatable<YourCorgi, Corgi> {
    public int MuchFluff { get; set; }
    public YourCorgi(int muchFluff) => MuchFluff = muchFluff;
    public Corgi Translate() => new(MuchFluff);
    public YourCorgi Translate(Corgi input) => new(input.FluffLevel);
}

// The fact that this is static is part of another task. Ignore that fact for the purposes of this review.
public static class YourCorgiService {
    public static bool RegisterCorgi(YourCorgi corgi, out string result) {
        result = $"Successfully registered corgi `{Guid.NewGuid()}` with a much fluff of `{corgi.MuchFluff}`.";
        return true;
    }
}

#endregion

#region My to Your Corgi Service Assembly

public class MyToYourCorgiRegistrationServiceHandler : ICorgiRegistrationServiceHandler {
    public bool TryFetchCorgis(out IEnumerable<Corgi> corgis) {
        var myCorgis = MyCorgiService.FetchCorgis(5);
        var translatedCorgis = new List<Corgi>();
        foreach (var corgi in myCorgis)
            translatedCorgis.Add(corgi.Translate());

        corgis = translatedCorgis;
        return true;
    }
    public void ProcessCorgi(Corgi corgi) {
        var yourCorgi = new YourCorgi(-1);
        yourCorgi = yourCorgi.Translate(corgi);
        if (YourCorgiService.RegisterCorgi(yourCorgi, out string registrationResult))
            Console.WriteLine(registrationResult);
    }
}

#endregion

#region Primary Service Assembly

public class CorgiRegistrationService {
    private ICorgiRegistrationServiceHandler _corgiServiceHandler;
    public CorgiRegistrationService(ICorgiRegistrationServiceHandler corgiServiceHandler) => _corgiServiceHandler = corgiServiceHandler;
    public void RegisterCorgis() {
        if (_corgiServiceHandler.TryFetchCorgis(out IEnumerable<Corgi> corgis))
            foreach (var corgi in corgis)
                _corgiServiceHandler.ProcessCorgi(corgi);
    }
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var _registrationService = new CorgiRegistrationService(new MyToYourCorgiRegistrationServiceHandler());
        _registrationService.RegisterCorgis();
    }
}

#endregion
```

The expected output of this example is five lines of text with different GUIDs and "fluff levels":

```
Successfully registered corgi `6d7afc29-4602-4815-95cb-1b36ab2c7359` with a much fluff of `69`.
Successfully registered corgi `13b9c564-a15f-4669-aaae-7908b5b7bd6e` with a much fluff of `80`.
Successfully registered corgi `4e8a8236-5251-48c1-af3c-32bb651841d3` with a much fluff of `82`.
Successfully registered corgi `78f5dcad-96cb-4764-be1d-adc2e1cf45cd` with a much fluff of `94`.
Successfully registered corgi `721d21fd-87c4-4530-9e24-b068a236ab53` with a much fluff of `79`.
```

Comment: What you're looking for seems to be extension methods. Unfortunately those are ... somewhat annoying with regards to polymorphism. Overall it seems like the underlying issue is the fact that you need to translate between multiple disjoint interfaces. That makes for a bad review on the code you presented, though, because it's obvious that your actual code looks completely different... Please reread [Why pseudocode is off-topic](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6080/)

Comment: @Vogel612 I've updated the post to clarify the issue and my solution to that issue. Additionally, the code has no *true* implementation yet, and this is a proof of concept so I've created data models and processes to support the proof of concept. The goal isn't to create extension methods but rather simplify how the translation happens on demand.